# Golang exec.Command how to run winscp?

Tags: windows, go

win11 Command Line:

```bash
winscp.com /ini=nul /log=script.log /script=c:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\script.tmp
```

The command is executed normally, but in golang:

```golang
    winscpcom := "d:\\WinSCP\\WinSCP.com"
    script := "c:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\script.tmp"
    cmd := exec.Command(winscpcom, "/ini=nul", "/log=script.log", "/script="+script)
    var out bytes.Buffer
    var stderr bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = &out
    cmd.Stderr = &stderr
    if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
        print(fmt.Sprint(err) + ": " + stderr.String())
        return
    }
```

report error: `exit status 1:`

only these

Why does exec.Command go wrong?

Comment: Is the log created?

Comment: exit status 1: is not a error

Comment: @MartinPrikryl log is not generated

Comment: @Para but the fact is that the program doesn't work, winscp not uploading anything

Comment: Did you try reading the `out`? (WinSCP does not print anything on `stderr` by default).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl yes, winscp not uploading anything